# Acceder a métodos de clases compuestas mediante reflexion en Java

Tags: java

A todos un cordial saludo. Necesito acceso a los métodos de una clase compuesta empleando la reflexión de Java, pero el resultado no es el esperado, ya que su construcción impide que los métodos tradicionales lean la información. Me pregunto, si existe una forma adecuada para hacerlo atendiendo la siguiente estructura:

```
public class Person {
  private double idPerson;
  private String namePerson;

  // Otros constructores, getters y setters de la clase Person aquí.
}

public class HeadBill {
  private Person person = new Person();
  private double numBill;
  private String dateBill;

  public HeadBill() {  }

  public HeadBill(Person person, double numBill, String dateBill) {
    this.person = person;
    this.numBill = numBill;
    this.dateBill = dateBill;
  }

  public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
  }
  public Person getPerson() {
    return this.person;
  }
  // Otros getters y setters de la clase HeadBill aquí.
}

public class ClaseInspectora {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HeadBill bill = new HeadBill();
    bill.person.setIdPerson(new Person(123456));
    bill.setNumBill(100);
    bill.setDateBill("2017-10-25");

    // Objeto Class con metadatos de la clase HeadBill:
    Class<? extends HeadBill> objClass = bill.getClass();
    // Informe de los métodos de la clase HeadBill:
    infoMetodos(objClass, bill);
  }

  public < T > void infoMetodos(Class classMetadat, T realObject) {
      throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
      NoSuchFieldException, InvocationTargetException
  {
    System.out.println("** Métodos clase " + classMetadat.getName()
        + " y valor retorno métodos -get-:");

    // Datos métodos de la clase:
    Method[] meths = classMetadat.getMethods();
    // Recorre lista de métodos:
    for (Method metodo : meths) {
      String sNomMetodo = metodo.getName();
      // Descarta métodos de Object:
      if (!metodo.toString().contains("java.lang.Object")) {
        // Selecciona métodos -get-:
        if (sNomMetodo.startsWith("get")) {
          // Cambia estado de acceso del método a accesible:
          if (!metodo.isAccessible()) metodo.setAccessible(true);
          System.out.println(metodo.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName()
              + "." + metodo.getName() + "() = " + metodo.invoke(realObject));
        } else { // Imprime nombre método Set:
          System.out.println(metodo.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName()
              + "." metodo.getName() + "()");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

El resultado de la rutina es la siguiente:

```
** Métodos clase tmpTest.HeadBill y valor retorno métodos -get-:
tmpTest.HeadBill.getPerson() = tmpTest.Person@70dea4e
tmpTest.HeadBill.getNumBill() = 100
tmpTest.HeadBill.getDateBill() = 2017-10-25
tmpTest.HeadBill.setPerson()
tmpTest.HeadBill.setNumBill()
tmpTest.HeadBill.setDateBill()
```

Se evidencia el resultado para ***"getNomPerson() = tmpTest.Person@70dea4e"*** cuyo valor no corresponde con el valor asignado, pues la referencia en el código no hace alusión directa al lugar donde dicho valor se aloja. ¿Existe una manera de llegar a ese valor y mostrarlo de forma correcta y genérica?, esto teniendo en cuenta, que dicho valor asociado puede ser cualquier otro, o incluso, la clase contenedora "Bill", puede establecer nuevos vínculos de asociación en cualquier momento.

Gracias por la información que me puedan brindar.

Comment: cual es la firma de `HeadBill.getNomPerson()` al parecer retorna un objeto `Person` y no un `String`

Comment: En efecto, había un pequeño error de taquigrafía. El código lo amplío para su mayor comprensión arriba. Tienes razón, se recibe un objeto Person, cuyo valor String, se consulta así: bill.getPerson().getIdPerson();  La reflexión en java me retorna el valor: bill.getPerson(), de ahí que requiero saber la forma de acceder a la ruta completa. Gracias.

Comment: Lo que podrias hacer es comparar la clase de lo retornado por la invocación del get, si es un primitivo o String imprimirlo, sino volver a invocar el metodo para obtener los getters del objeto retornado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando pintas un objeto con System.out.println, lo que hace java por defecto es invocar el método toString() del objeto en cuestión que le pasas a la función "println".

En el caso de Person, al ser un objeto creado por el programador (por tí en este caso), el comportamiento por defecto del método toString() de esa clase es pintar el propio nombre de la clase. De ahí "tmpTest.Person@70dea4e".

Si lo que quieres es evitar esto y seguir pintando cada uno de métodos, a su vez, de la clase person, tienes varias soluciones:

**Solución 1:**

Añade el siguiente método a la clase Person:

```
public String toString() {
   infoMetodos(this.getClass(),this);
}
```

Si creas nuevas clases, añadeles el mismo método toString.

**Solución 2:**

Cambia esto:

```
System.out.println(metodo.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName()
              + "." + metodo.getName() + "() = " + metodo.invoke(realObject));
```

por esto:

```
if (metodo.getReturnType().equals(Person.class)) {
   infoMetodos(metodo.getReturnType(),metodo.invoke(realObject));
}
else {
   System.out.println(metodo.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName()
              + "." + metodo.getName() + "() = " + metodo.invoke(realObject));
}
```

Si añades nuevas clases, deberas comparar el tipo de clase de realObject con ellas, además de con Person.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el interés, tiempo y tentativas soluciones. Desafortunadamente las propuestas no han surtido el efecto esperado, esto porque aplicando la Solución 2, el objeto **realObject** nunca llega a ser de tipo Person, pues los metadatos que llegan al método son de HeadBill y allí, nunca dejan de serlo. Todo esto provoca, que al intentar aplicar la solución 2, el programa jamás encuentra una instancia de Person, y por ende, la salida es idéntica a la ya mostrada. **getMethods()** opera métodos de "HeadBill", y getPerson() es uno de ellos, no lo interpreta como instancia de "Person".

Comment: Disculpa, edito la solución 2. Hay que comparar la clase del tipo devuelto por cada función y no del propio objeto si no efectivamente la solución no vale.

Comment: Es correcto. La solución 2 entrega el valor asociado al método compuesto de la clase HeadBill como se espera. Muchas gracias y un cordial saludo.

Comment: Si es correcto marca esta solución como valida para que sirva al resto de usuarios.

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero una corrección: `al ser un objeto creado por el programador (por tí en este caso), el comportamiento por defecto del método toString`. No tiene nada que ver con quién ha creado el objeto (aunque supongo que te refieres a la clase). Tiene que ver con si la clase está heredando la implementación de `toString()` de `Object` u otra implementación.